# hsqldb count for each day

Tags: sql, hsqldb

having table

```
id|date|somefield
```

I need to get count of entries for each day of the year

```
select EXTRACT (DAY_OF_YEAR FROM date) as day, id from table
```

works fine

but when I try

```
select EXTRACT (DAY_OF_YEAR FROM date) as day, count(*) from table
```

fails

```
select count(*) from table group by EXTRACT (DAY_OF_YEAR FROM date)
```

fails as well

Comment: how about, `select EXTRACT (DAY_OF_YEAR FROM date) as day, count(*) from tableGROUP BY EXTRACT (DAY_OF_YEAR FROM date)` ?

Comment: wat fails ? you got error or what ? if yes what error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `group by` expression.  Here is some pseudo code, I will work up a SqlFiddle in a moment.

```
select EXTRACT (DAY_OF_YEAR FROM date) as day, 
count(*) 
from table
group by EXTRACT (DAY_OF_YEAR FROM date)
```

**SQLFIDDLE (Using MYSQL)** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42c9e/10